# Roots of the polynomial $z^4+4z^3+6z^2-4z+4$ in the circle $|z+1|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, rouches-theorem

I came across the following problem:

Find the number of zeros of $P(z)=z^4+4z^3+6z^2-4z+4$ in the circle $|z+1|<1$. I know that I can't apply Rouche's Theorem directly since we don't have a condition of the form $|z|<M$ and thus bounding the polynomial is hard. I also tried applying the Cauchy's Argument Principle but I couldn't compute the integral $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z+1|<1} \frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}=\text{Ind}_{f \circ \gamma}(0),$$
where $\gamma:=|z+1|<1$.

Also, here's a solution I thought:
$$
P(z)=(z+1)^4-8(z+1)+11
$$
and in $|z+1|=1$, the term $11$ dominates, so
$$
|P(z)-11| \leq |(z+1)^4-8(z+1)| \leq |z+1|^4+|8(z+1)| =9<11,
$$
so by Rouché's theorem the polynomial doesn't have any roots in $|z+1|<1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: Write P(z) as a function of $w = z + 1$. The polynomial becomes a lot easier to analyze.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I'm not sure of the solution. Either way I edited my question

Comment: @Tropax It looks right to me.

Comment: @Tropax That works and it's even easier than that. As you saw, by the triangle inequality you have $|P(z+1) - 11| \leq  |(z + 1)^4| + |8(z+1)| \leq 9$, so that $|P(z+1)|$ is between $2$ and $20$... Rouche isn't even needed.